# Ckeditor instance ready is not firing in chrome(some systems only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ckeditor, instance

Am using code as below:

```
CKEDITOR.inline(document.getElementById('a'), {
     toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript']
});

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
     alert("HI");
});
```

Ckeditor oninstanceready function is not firing in some system with chrome brower but its working in firefox on the same system.

OS: Windows 7,
Brower : chrome 29.0.1547,
CKeditor 4.0.

Please help me out this issue

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What version of CKeditor do you use ?

Comment: Ckeditor version is 4.0

Comment: add some additional details in your question about OS,browser and etc.

Comment: In case of weird issues like this. Use the "replacebycode" sample that comes with CKEditor, add the minimum amount of code that you want to check (here: just the instanceReady event handler) and run it in Chrome in "New Incognito Window". Some broken extension may be responsible for this, as well as some code on your website which for example triggers a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 3):

The inline method return the CKeditor instance
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KRKKC/3/

Try this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(document.getElementById('a'), {
    toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'],
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            alert ('im ready');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Chrome ? (PC, MAC ?)

Comment: chrome version 29, Windows 7

Comment: What's supposed to be happening with this fiddle? Is an alert supposed to pop up?  How to trigger this?  Have tried both Firefox and Chrome...